# sending a virtual box machine/server or opensource application to the tv via chromecast

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualhost, chromecast

I haven't done any chromecast or oracle VirtualBox development so before I spend to much time I would like to know the feasibility of the following.

My understanding is that I can wrap my application to work with chromecast. Hence,I should be able to wrap an open source project to utilize chromecast.

Therefore,I'm thinking (or possibly lack of thinking) I should be able to use the virtual box source code to embed and compile the chromecast functionality into the virtualbox? Then run the virtual box with the chromecast ability.

https://www.virtualbox.org/

So what are your thoughts on the feasibility to make virtual box or other open source applications shareable via chromecast using the method above.

thanks in advance for you feedback.

Comment: Your question is too vague, it is not clear what you'd like to do, how the virtual box enters the picture, etc. It might be beneficial to give a use case that you have in mind as well.

Comment: 1. I would like to share my virtual box client that is running on my PC to my tv using chromecast.

I have the opensource code for the virtual box. Therefore I'm thinking that I should be able to embed and utilize the chromecast  api to do this. Is this possible?

Comment: I think you need to do some research and educate yourself on what exactly a virtual machine is and how it works. Half of your question makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: Care to be of help and elaborate which part was too confusing for you? Are you even familiar or even heard of googlecast development, perhaps that is the confusion?  I don't know where your stapler is.

Answer (score 0):

My question was can I embed the googlecast api into an opensource project like virtualbox and have the output sent to my tv. It had nothing to do with how virtualbox works hence I said any opensource project.

I think I answered my own question at this point and I think it could have been answered rather quickly by someone with googlecast experience.

The answer appears to be NO, because of several reasons but mainly:

From https://developers.google.com/cast/developing_a_sender

1. The sender device can be Android or iOS applications, or a Chrome app. I wouldn't be interested in running a vm on any of those devices nor do I think its even an option. So no I couldn't share my virtual box client that is running on my PC to my tv using chromecast api.
2. It appears that googlecast API is more geared to video and audio casting and perhaps its limited on what user input it can capture without making it awkward for the user to say the least.